# Powercenter (or informatica)performance issue

Tags: session, insert-update, informatica-powercenter

My powercenter version is 8.6.1.
I designed a mapping and a session , and i checked "insert" and "update else insert" in the session settings.
I found that the rate of data dealing was only 200 rows/s or so.
By unchecking "update else insert", the rate could reach to 10000 rows/s.
The target table had an index ，and i examined the execution plan, the index worked.
And i executed update sql statement in DB (oracle), it took less than one second to update nearly 1 million rows. So it wouldn't be the DB problems.
Did anyone run into the same problem？Is there something wrong in my session settings？
Any help would be pleasure！

Comment: When you are updating through Informatica, it executes update query for each row (1 million update queries), even if you are updating the same value. But in DB you are probably executing a single update query to update 1 million rows. If you will be updating the same value for all rows, you can consider using post session SQL query.

Comment: But i still have to insert the rows that do not exist in DB. As you describe, it sounds a little silly of informatica's update strategy... why still many companys use this tool ?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it is silly, it is the does cater to most common scenarios. When you have large volume of data to be updated, you have to customize/tune your mapping to improve performance. If you want to update multiple rows with same value in a single update, use an update strategy transformation with a separate target instance and connect only the ports in WHERE and SET clauses of your DB query. You would also want to pass only distinct records to be updated to that target.

Comment: But i need to implement a "merge" like operation

Comment: @Jason your complaint sounds to me like "if I'm using a hammer for screws, it's working very bad. Why do people use hammers?". It's a tool and it's very powerful - if used in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Informatica tries inserting. If it encounters an error, it's updating. For each and every row individually.
Instead use a lookup and properly mark rows for insert or update. Use 'Data Driven' on session property. To increase the performance even more, verify if there are any changes - if row is exactly the same, filter it. This will perform updated only when it's really required, limiting the number of operations.

Comment: But that increase the cost in another meaning, and also the complexity of the mapping. If developers have to use the lookup widget instead, why should the official software still keep this option?

Comment: It's a tool. And you need to use it the right way. Complexity of the mapping is not an issue. The choice whether to use the lookup or "update else insert" depends on scenario you have. The latter is better on case you've got millions of rows with very few updates.

Comment: Maybe you are right, i just want to figure out a simple and better way to implement a "merge" like operation.

Comment: I used to work with datastage before, and i found its "update then insert" perform better than informatica. it updates a batch rows each time,not like informatica does one row each time as Samik said.

Comment: What can I say... Informatica works in a different way. Try to "learn" how it works rather then "expect" it to work in some way. I'll be happy to explain how things work or how to achieve some result. I won't be able to make it work in a way you'r expect ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the commit interval setting? Its default is usually around 10000 rows per commit. Worth pushing it up to a higher number your system can manage i.e. 100000 should becsafe and give an indication, most oracle systems can manage 1 million depending on the size of the target table rows. Yes Informatica has a commit interval but it is configurable

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Bulk update is not possible in Informatica. Even if you set the mode to bulk, informatica will change it to Normal which you can see in session log.

Best way is, allow router to decide whether to insert or update the data before hitting the DB. You could you MD5() method to compare the data/columns real fast also try to utilize Dynamic lookup incase if you feel source contains duplicates.